# What is the aspnetcore-browser-refresh and where/how to add it?

Tags: .net-core, .net-7.0, hot-reload

I upgraded an ASP.NET Core 5 web application to .NET 7.0, when I launch the project now I have the log:

> [16:27:58.353 INF] HTTP GET / responded 200 in 131.6933
> ms(Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware) [16:27:58.361 WRN]
> Unable to configure browser refresh script injection on the response.
> Consider manually adding `<script src="/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js"></script>`  to the
> body of the page.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware)

What is that, how do I get this script, from where, should it be loaded only in development mode etc?

I saw this article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-hot-reload/ however it does not explain what to do in .NET 7 and how to get rid of this warning/error. I can't load the localhost because of it....

I added this to the end of my `_Layout.cshtml`

```
    @await RenderSectionAsync("scripts", required: false).ConfigureAwait(false)
    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js"></script>
    </environment>
</body>
</html>
```

However it does not change the output message when I restarted the project.

No idea where from it will serve this js file... I have no code of it...

I read also this one

https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/31949

but I have any `UseResponseCompression()` in the project...